# Guessing game for ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I'm currently trying to create a simply made guessing game, In the code there will be three set number (for now) that a person has to guess. If he/she guesses all the numbers correctly it puts, "Congrats, you win!"

Now as a beginning test i just wanted the user to guess one number correctly and the code gives back correct or incorrect.

```
random_guess = [1, 3, 5]

puts "Please Pick a number, 1-5"
pick_num = gets.chomp

if pick_num == random_guess = true
    puts "Correct!"
else
    puts "Incorrect!"
end
```

(I know this code is very beginner, i'm very new to ruby.) for some reason every time i run this program it puts incorrect.

Comment: it will be great if you can show some courtesy of providing feedback to people who take out their time to help you out. Even a criticism/negetive feedback is better than no feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is wrong. It should be:

```
if random_guess.include? pick_num.to_i
```

Note that if you leave off the `to_i` the equality check will always fail because you're comparing the integer 3 against the string "3".

Just to help you a bit more. Since your end goal is to have the user guess all the numbers correctly. You can just loop on the same if statement I wrote above. And every time they guess a correct number you can remove it from the array like such:
`random_guess.delete(pick_num.to_i)`

Once the array is empty, the user has won.

Comment: At the point of making the program i was just looking for an almost test program to go one step at a time. But that is helpful for a full program. one more question is if i would say: '5.times do random_guess.delete(pick_num.to_i)' would that be a legitemate loop, so the user would only have severeal chances to guess a number?

Answer (score 0):

Making `random_guess` random:

```
random_guess = []
3.times{random_guess << rand(1..5)}
random_guess
# => [5, 1, 4] # will be random in every other iteration
```

Checking if the number exists, you can either use `index` or `include?`:

```
if random_guess.index(pick_num.to_i) # alternatively random_guess.index(pick_num.to_i)
 puts "Correct!"
else
 puts "Incorrect!"
end
```

**Why is your code always printing incorrect?**

You are doing `if pick_num == random_guess = true`, which is a blunder. What is actually happening here is:

- you are assigning `true` to `random_guess`. i.e. irrespective to what value (Array) `random_guess` holds, you are overwriting it with `true`.
- Then you are comparing  `random_guess` with `pick_num`.

So essentially you are doing this:

```
if pick_num == (random_guess = true) # say pick_num = "1"
# "1" == true # which is obviously false.
```

The correct conditional statement should be:

```
if pick_num == random_guess
```

However this will also print `false` every time. Reason?

- `pick_num` is a string.
- `random_guess` is an array that contains integer values.
- You are comparing two different object types. So its always `false`.

Therefore the right way to solve this is checking whether the user entered value exists in the Array. For that you can use [Array#index](http://ruby-doc.org//core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-index) or [Array#include?](http://ruby-doc.org//core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F). Hence the statement in my proposed solution:

```
if random_guess.index(pick_num.to_i)
```

**NOTE**: `pick_num.to_i` converts `pick_num` (a character) into an integer. This is required as your array contains only integers and not characters.

Comment: (sorry for the extremely late answer) The conversion to integer i should've seen. And i didn't learn about the index, so that is extremely helpful to learn, thank you!